# Force enable push notification iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

When we register for push notification on iOS we get a message "My App" would like to send you push notifications "Don't Allow" and "OK". 
How can I force "OK". This is not for an App store app, so App rejections is not an issue.

Comment: I think what Apple is trying to say here is: "Don't second-guess the user. Let them decide." Also, this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: If App is targeted towards App Store users then yes. But in my case I have to force enable push notifications.

Comment: i dont hink u can do that,at first time when asks the allow didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
it is called,u can not call this delegate method to send device token to ur server

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev: Yes, but I need to register for Push Notifications to pass device token to device management software

Comment: Why the question got downvoted

Comment: Because what you're trying to do is explicitly user-hostile. iOS provides for centralized device management, just not on the app level. Google for "iPhone MDM".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App approval isn't really the issue. What you're asking for is something the OS is *specifically* designed to *not* allow. Thus, any method you found to make it work would be an exploit that, at best, would be subject to patching, breaking your app. At worst, it could effect the stability of the device and any data contained therein.